# Menu right arrow hides on hover

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I' am trying to make a menu which will have a arrow on its right. On hover of the menu, The arrow will change to another arrow color and the background color will change to orange.

The menu works fine when its NOT on HOVER state but when HOVER on the MENU the Arrow hides aways. I have tried with the following code but can't seem to find out what am doing wrong.

HTML

```
  <div class="sidebar_pages">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Who we are</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">What we do</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Philosophy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Partners</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.sidebar_pages ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar_pages ul li{
    background: url(../images/a2_18.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 270px 15px;
}

.sidebar_pages ul li:hover{
    background: url(../images/a1_09.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 270px 15px;
}

.sidebar_pages ul li a{
    line-height: 42px !important;
    height: 42px !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar_pages ul li a:hover{
    background: #e17226 !important;
    color: #FFF !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/ocefem/1/edit

```
.sidebar_pages ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar_pages ul li{
    background: url(../images/a2_18.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 270px 15px;
}

.sidebar_pages ul li:hover{
    background: #e17226  url(../images/a1_09.png) no-repeat;   /*changed*/
    background-position: 270px 15px;
}

.sidebar_pages ul li a{
    line-height: 42px !important;
    height: 42px !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar_pages ul li a:hover{
    /*background: #e17226 !important;*/                       /* removed */
    color: #FFF !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like your:

```
background: #e17226 !important;
```

is overriding the

```
background: url(../images/a1_09.png) no-repeat;
```

if you change it to:

```
background: #e17266 url(../images/a1_09.png) no-repeat;
```

for the li:hover and remove the a:hover background option then it should work the way you want it to

Answer (score 0):

Rule #1 of list-based menus: **style the A-tag, not the LI**.